# Why does select for update locked almost the table entirely?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have learned MySQL and InnoDB for a while, but this SQL and it's locking still confused me.

When I was in `repeatable read`, and using a small table just like MySQL doc providing.

```
mysql> desc child;
+-------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> set session transaction isolation level repeatable read;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from child;
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
|  89 |
|  90 |
| 102 |
| 151 |
+-----+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

In this case, I begin a transaction and type a SQL, enter but not commit for session yet.

And after that, I query the locks using `performance_schema.data_locks`.

As you can see, there are 6 locks in this table at this moment.

- IX for table
- Next-Key Lock (151, positive infinity)
- Next-Key Lock (89, 90]
- Next-Key Lock (90, 102]
- Next-Key Lock (102, 151]
- Next-Key Lock (negative infinity, 89]

We has notice that there are only 4 records in this table, and there are 5 Next-Key Locks in this table too, thus almost entire table have been locked.

```
mysql> begin;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM child WHERE id >= 102 for update;
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
| 102 |
| 151 |
+-----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from performance_schema.data_locks\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               ENGINE: INNODB
       ENGINE_LOCK_ID: 140616303284368:1158:140616462870928
ENGINE_TRANSACTION_ID: 4592
            THREAD_ID: 80
             EVENT_ID: 14
        OBJECT_SCHEMA: xhinliang_test
          OBJECT_NAME: child
       PARTITION_NAME: NULL
    SUBPARTITION_NAME: NULL
           INDEX_NAME: NULL
OBJECT_INSTANCE_BEGIN: 140616462870928
            LOCK_TYPE: TABLE
            LOCK_MODE: IX
          LOCK_STATUS: GRANTED
            LOCK_DATA: NULL // IX of table
*************************** 2. row ***************************
               ENGINE: INNODB
       ENGINE_LOCK_ID: 140616303284368:3:4:1:140616474499104
ENGINE_TRANSACTION_ID: 4592
            THREAD_ID: 80
             EVENT_ID: 14
        OBJECT_SCHEMA: xhinliang_test
          OBJECT_NAME: child
       PARTITION_NAME: NULL
    SUBPARTITION_NAME: NULL
           INDEX_NAME: PRIMARY
OBJECT_INSTANCE_BEGIN: 140616474499104
            LOCK_TYPE: RECORD
            LOCK_MODE: X
          LOCK_STATUS: GRANTED
            LOCK_DATA: supremum pseudo-record // Next-Key Lock (151, positive infinity)
*************************** 3. row ***************************
               ENGINE: INNODB
       ENGINE_LOCK_ID: 140616303284368:3:4:2:140616474499104
ENGINE_TRANSACTION_ID: 4592
            THREAD_ID: 80
             EVENT_ID: 14
        OBJECT_SCHEMA: xhinliang_test
          OBJECT_NAME: child
       PARTITION_NAME: NULL
    SUBPARTITION_NAME: NULL
           INDEX_NAME: PRIMARY
OBJECT_INSTANCE_BEGIN: 140616474499104
            LOCK_TYPE: RECORD
            LOCK_MODE: X
          LOCK_STATUS: GRANTED
            LOCK_DATA: 90 // Next-Key Lock (89, 90]
*************************** 4. row ***************************
               ENGINE: INNODB
       ENGINE_LOCK_ID: 140616303284368:3:4:3:140616474499104
ENGINE_TRANSACTION_ID: 4592
            THREAD_ID: 80
             EVENT_ID: 14
        OBJECT_SCHEMA: xhinliang_test
          OBJECT_NAME: child
       PARTITION_NAME: NULL
    SUBPARTITION_NAME: NULL
           INDEX_NAME: PRIMARY
OBJECT_INSTANCE_BEGIN: 140616474499104
            LOCK_TYPE: RECORD
            LOCK_MODE: X
          LOCK_STATUS: GRANTED
            LOCK_DATA: 102 // Next-Key Lock (90, 102]
*************************** 5. row ***************************
               ENGINE: INNODB
       ENGINE_LOCK_ID: 140616303284368:3:4:4:140616474499104
ENGINE_TRANSACTION_ID: 4592
            THREAD_ID: 80
             EVENT_ID: 14
        OBJECT_SCHEMA: xhinliang_test
          OBJECT_NAME: child
       PARTITION_NAME: NULL
    SUBPARTITION_NAME: NULL
           INDEX_NAME: PRIMARY
OBJECT_INSTANCE_BEGIN: 140616474499104
            LOCK_TYPE: RECORD
            LOCK_MODE: X
          LOCK_STATUS: GRANTED
            LOCK_DATA: 151 // Next-Key Lock (102, 151]
*************************** 6. row ***************************
               ENGINE: INNODB
       ENGINE_LOCK_ID: 140616303284368:3:4:5:140616474499104
ENGINE_TRANSACTION_ID: 4592
            THREAD_ID: 80
             EVENT_ID: 14
        OBJECT_SCHEMA: xhinliang_test
          OBJECT_NAME: child
       PARTITION_NAME: NULL
    SUBPARTITION_NAME: NULL
           INDEX_NAME: PRIMARY
OBJECT_INSTANCE_BEGIN: 140616474499104
            LOCK_TYPE: RECORD
            LOCK_MODE: X
          LOCK_STATUS: GRANTED
            LOCK_DATA: 89 // Next-Key Lock (negative infinity, 89]
```

I begin another session at the same time, try to insert some rows, but all failed.

```
mysql> insert into child (id) values (88);
^C^C -- query aborted
ERROR 1317 (70100): Query execution was interrupted
mysql> insert into child (id) values (88);
^C^C -- query aborted
ERROR 1317 (70100): Query execution was interrupted
mysql> insert into child (id) values (91);
^C^C -- query aborted
ERROR 1317 (70100): Query execution was interrupted
mysql> insert into child (id) values (100);
^C^C -- query aborted
ERROR 1317 (70100): Query execution was interrupted
mysql> insert into child (id) values (103);
^C^C -- query aborted
ERROR 1317 (70100): Query execution was interrupted
mysql> insert into child (id) values (152);
^C^C -- query aborted
ERROR 1317 (70100): Query execution was interrupted
```

To my thought, it should be 3 Next-Key locks but not 5 in this case.

Because the doc of InnoDB said

> InnoDB locks the index range scanned, using gap locks or next-key

So the Next-Key Lock of (89, 90] should not be appear, and the Next-Key Lock of (90, 102] should be replace to a Record Lock for id 102.

Look at this SQL and response, can somebody tell me what happened?

Comment: "can somebody tell me what happened?", you answered your own question: "almost entire table have been locked"

Comment: Why does "almost entire table have been locked", that's my question.

Comment: It is because you have only 4 records in your table. Try to test with more records, and you will see that, when selecting only 2 records, you will have only 2 (record) locks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Luuk, I inserted some more rows and retry.

This time I got my supposed response.

```
mysql> begin;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from child;
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
|  89 |
|  90 |
| 102 |
| 151 |
| 388 |
| 390 |
| 452 |
| 882 |
+-----+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM child WHERE id >= 388 for update;
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
| 388 |
| 390 |
| 452 |
| 882 |
+-----+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from performance_schema.data_locks\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               ENGINE: INNODB
       ENGINE_LOCK_ID: 140616303284368:1158:140616462870928
ENGINE_TRANSACTION_ID: 4609
            THREAD_ID: 80
             EVENT_ID: 36
        OBJECT_SCHEMA: xhinliang_test
          OBJECT_NAME: child
       PARTITION_NAME: NULL
    SUBPARTITION_NAME: NULL
           INDEX_NAME: NULL
OBJECT_INSTANCE_BEGIN: 140616462870928
            LOCK_TYPE: TABLE
            LOCK_MODE: IX
          LOCK_STATUS: GRANTED
            LOCK_DATA: NULL // IX for table
*************************** 2. row ***************************
               ENGINE: INNODB
       ENGINE_LOCK_ID: 140616303284368:3:4:6:140616474499104
ENGINE_TRANSACTION_ID: 4609
            THREAD_ID: 80
             EVENT_ID: 36
        OBJECT_SCHEMA: xhinliang_test
          OBJECT_NAME: child
       PARTITION_NAME: NULL
    SUBPARTITION_NAME: NULL
           INDEX_NAME: PRIMARY
OBJECT_INSTANCE_BEGIN: 140616474499104
            LOCK_TYPE: RECORD
            LOCK_MODE: X,REC_NOT_GAP
          LOCK_STATUS: GRANTED
            LOCK_DATA: 388 // Record Lock for 388
*************************** 3. row ***************************
               ENGINE: INNODB
       ENGINE_LOCK_ID: 140616303284368:3:4:1:140616474499448
ENGINE_TRANSACTION_ID: 4609
            THREAD_ID: 80
             EVENT_ID: 36
        OBJECT_SCHEMA: xhinliang_test
          OBJECT_NAME: child
       PARTITION_NAME: NULL
    SUBPARTITION_NAME: NULL
           INDEX_NAME: PRIMARY
OBJECT_INSTANCE_BEGIN: 140616474499448
            LOCK_TYPE: RECORD
            LOCK_MODE: X
          LOCK_STATUS: GRANTED
            LOCK_DATA: supremum pseudo-record // Next-Key Lock for (882, +inf)
*************************** 4. row ***************************
               ENGINE: INNODB
       ENGINE_LOCK_ID: 140616303284368:3:4:7:140616474499448
ENGINE_TRANSACTION_ID: 4609
            THREAD_ID: 80
             EVENT_ID: 36
        OBJECT_SCHEMA: xhinliang_test
          OBJECT_NAME: child
       PARTITION_NAME: NULL
    SUBPARTITION_NAME: NULL
           INDEX_NAME: PRIMARY
OBJECT_INSTANCE_BEGIN: 140616474499448
            LOCK_TYPE: RECORD
            LOCK_MODE: X
          LOCK_STATUS: GRANTED
            LOCK_DATA: 390 // Next-Key Lock for (388, 390]
*************************** 5. row ***************************
               ENGINE: INNODB
       ENGINE_LOCK_ID: 140616303284368:3:4:8:140616474499448
ENGINE_TRANSACTION_ID: 4609
            THREAD_ID: 80
             EVENT_ID: 36
        OBJECT_SCHEMA: xhinliang_test
          OBJECT_NAME: child
       PARTITION_NAME: NULL
    SUBPARTITION_NAME: NULL
           INDEX_NAME: PRIMARY
OBJECT_INSTANCE_BEGIN: 140616474499448
            LOCK_TYPE: RECORD
            LOCK_MODE: X
          LOCK_STATUS: GRANTED
            LOCK_DATA: 452 // Next-Key Lock for (390, 452]
*************************** 6. row ***************************
               ENGINE: INNODB
       ENGINE_LOCK_ID: 140616303284368:3:4:9:140616474499448
ENGINE_TRANSACTION_ID: 4609
            THREAD_ID: 80
             EVENT_ID: 36
        OBJECT_SCHEMA: xhinliang_test
          OBJECT_NAME: child
       PARTITION_NAME: NULL
    SUBPARTITION_NAME: NULL
           INDEX_NAME: PRIMARY
OBJECT_INSTANCE_BEGIN: 140616474499448
            LOCK_TYPE: RECORD
            LOCK_MODE: X
          LOCK_STATUS: GRANTED
            LOCK_DATA: 882 // Next-Key Lock for (452, 882]
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

In this case, we can see the locks we suppose to see.

- IX for table
- Record Lock for 388
- Next-Key Lock for (882, +inf)
- Next-Key Lock for (388, 390]
- Next-Key Lock for (390, 452]
- Next-Key Lock for (452, 882]

Answer (score -2):

This is the normal behavior when doing SELECT FOR UPDATE.

You can check it out the official docs here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: No, I would not expect the insertion of 88 to be blocked.